# Bourbaki assembly brackets

Tags: math-mode, brackets

In the "Theory of Sets" of N. Bourbaki in russian translation I've found that assemblies have very cute brackets.

If anyone knows how to produce them?

The only similar shape I found is `\leftsquigarrow` from `mathabx` package.

[image]

Comment: The `stix` package has ⧘ `\lvzigzag` and ⧙ `\rvzigzag`, which are quite similar. These two characters are encoded in Unicode as LEFT WIGGLY FENCE (U+29D8) and RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE (U+29D9).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BONUS: Works across math styles

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ulem,scalerel,rotating}
\newcommand\bkl{\mathopen{\stretchrel*{\rotatebox{90}{\uwave{\rule{3ex}{0pt}}}}{Xy}}}
\newcommand\bkr{\mathclose{\stretchrel*{\rotatebox{90}{\uwave{\rule{3ex}{0pt}}}}{Xy}}}
\begin{document}
$A \bkl x, y \bkr.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Width could be tweaked a little with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ulem,scalerel,rotating}
\newcommand\bkl{\mathopen{%
  \stretchrel*[180]{\mkern-1mu\rotatebox{90}{\uwave{\rule{3ex}{0pt}}}}{Xy}}}
\newcommand\bkr{\mathclose{%
  \stretchrel*[180]{\mkern-1mu\rotatebox{90}{\uwave{\rule{3ex}{0pt}}}}{Xy}}}
\begin{document}
$A \bkl x, y \bkr.$

$\scriptstyle A \bkl x, y \bkr.$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \bkl x, y \bkr.$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `stix` package has ⧘ `\lvzigzag` and ⧙ `\rvzigzag`, which resemble the image you posted and may even be semantically the same. These two characters are encoded in Unicode as LEFT WIGGLY FENCE (U+29D8) and RIGHT WIGGLY FENCE (U+29D9).

So, you can either use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
$A \rvzigzag x, y \lvzigzag$
\end{document}
```

or, with Unicode support, you need a font that supports ⧘ and ⧙ such as STIX2Math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX2Math.otf}

\begin{document}
$A ⧙ x, y ⧘$
\end{document}
```

Sorry, I totally don’t understand the use of both characters, so their use and the notation may be completely wrong in my example.

[image]

Comment: I believe that these are indeed based on the Bourbaki example.  If my memory is correct, a Bourbaki example was the source of the request to add these to Unicode.

Comment: Strangely, the LEFT WIGGLY FENCE starts and ends its wiggle to the left. I would rather think that it should be the other way around.

Comment: I no longer have access to the materials used to compile the STIX request to Unicode, so I can't check.  But what you suggest is certainly possible.  However, at least some Bourbaki papers are online in scanned form, so with luck, an example might be found.

Answer (score 1):

You could import `\lfilet` and `\rfilet` from a scaled down version of the font `mathx10` from `mathabx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{<-> s*[0.5] mathx10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lfilet}{4}{mathx}{"37}{mathx}{"37}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rfilet}{5}{mathx}{"3F}{mathx}{"3F}

\begin{document}

\[
A\,\bigl\lfilet\, x,y \,\bigr\rfilet.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that these delimiters are only available in `\big` size or larger.